# application deployment in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

For some reason suddenly I am unable to deploy my current application in bluemix server, every time I deploy it fails with following error

> Error: Invalid application deployment information for: econfig-poc-backend-adapter - Unable to deploy or start application - Missing application deployment information.. Please delete the module and re-deploy the application.

Same application I am able to deploy form Command line interface using CF tools, but there the new war is not regenerated, I am not sure what is missing in the environment. Will appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: are you deploying using the Eclipse-plugin for Bluemix? or command line interface (CF utility)?

Comment: Could you please also clarify "there the new war in not regenerate"

Comment: The error I am getting is when running from eclipse plugin

Comment: @rspoglia When I am deploying using CF Utility, it is picking up the old war file, I am not sure when that war is suppose to get updated or regenerated, but if I run build.xml explicitly then war does gets updated.

Comment: Within the eclipse framework you can right click on the project and select export -> war file. This action is not automatically triggered during the build.

Comment: This does but then there is a manual process, I am looking for automatically build when deploying application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your Eclipse, delete the application from the Servers window under Bluemix and deploy it again.

`cf push` is a tool to push artifacts to Bluemix. It will not build your java files.

To push your application manually (Eclipse not involved), you have to build the war first, and then push the war. If its an ant based project (build.xml) you will need to run `ant`. If its maven (pom.xml), you will need to run `mvn package`. Then, you push the generated war file `cf push appname -p path/to/file.war`

You can also have Eclipse generate the war for you. Right click on your project in Eclipse and find the option to Export a war file. You can then push this war file using the command above.